Serializing/Deserializing a transaction
Got two questions.
I. have created a transaction on the client. I have two options:

Serialize it, then convert it to a blob and send it to the backend, or;
Convert it to a blob and send it to the backend then serialize it on the backend.

From the backend I suppose I would need to define a struct then unpack the bytes into that struct. But if i have it already serialized then I would need to unserialize it first then unpack it into a struct which makes me think perhaps serializing it on the backend is better.

I am using rust and actix on backend

#[post("/serialized_tx")]
async fn send_and_confirm_transaction(
    body: web::Bytes,
    rpc_client: web::Data<Arc<RpcClient>>,
) -> impl Responder {
    println!("bytes length -> {:?}", body.len());

    HttpResponse::Ok()
}

I am curious as to how I would approach unpacking this. I was looking at the raw uint8array and it has quiet a few fields in it. So i suppose I wouldn't declare each one of these fields but I would use the solana type Transaction and unpack the bytes to that. Would be curious to know if they are any examples out there…

Sent the payload as a JSON.
        const body = JSON.stringify({
          tx_id,
          serialized_tx,
        });

        const res = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8080/serialized_tx', {
          method: 'POST',
          body,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        });

Then deserialized it to check validity and serialized back again to send to validator.
